# No such file to load - bundler on Passenger on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I installed Passenger (not the nginx version) to my Ubuntu Natty Narwhal machine and also installed bundler on the root directory of my app `/home/app/insight/current`.

Below are some variables

```
turing@machine:~/insight/current$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/app/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

turing@machine:~/insight/current$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

turing@machine:~/insight/current$ which rvm
/home/app/.rvm/bin/rvm

turing@machine:~/insight/current$ which bundler

turing@machine:~/insight/current$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle

turing@machine:~/insight/current$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]

turing@machine:~/insight/current$ rvm gem list
/home/app/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /var in PATH, mode 040777

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.17)
rake (0.8.7 ruby)
```

Is it an issue where Passenger is using a different version of Ruby than I expect it to be using? What do I need to remove or change?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `which ruby` output it seems that the ruby version being used is the system one and not the one from RVM.

Make sure you run `rvm --default 1.9.2` to have the RVM ruby be the default.

Comment: I also restarted the server, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: When you run `which ruby`, did the output change?